# jquery clickable div

Tags: jquery

click here

I want to make that div clickable and it should trigger following function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#generate").click(function(){
        $("#quote p").load("script.php");
    });
});
</script>
```

how can I make that work?

Answer (score 5):

Give the `div` the ID `generate` or any other (of course reasonable) ID to uniquely select it:

```
<div id="someid" class="clickme"> click here </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#someid").click(function(){
        $("#quote p").load("script.php");
    });
});
</script>
```

Note that an ID has to be **unique** throughout the document.

You can also just use the class to select the element, but this will select any element with this class and bind the handler to all of these:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".clickme").click(function(){
        $("#quote p").load("script.php");
    });
});
```

Read the documentation about [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), especially [ID](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) and [class](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) selectors.

Answer (score 3):

Either give the `<div>` an `id` of `generate`:

```
<div id="generate">
```

or replace `#generate` by `.clickme` in the JS:

```
$('.clickme').click(function() {
    // ...
});
```

This is pretty trivial. To learn more about using jQuery, I warmly recommend to go through [their tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials). If you prefer a book, then I recommend [jQuery in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988355).